# property flex-wrap not working correctly?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to understand the flexbox. My goal is to align 3 items on each line.
I have to use the property `flex-wrap : wrap;`  but, my problem is that I  align 4 items on my first line.

```
.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap : wrap; 
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answer.

```css
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap : wrap; 

}

/* disposition du cadre */
.box{
  margin-top: 33px;
  width: 21%;/*
  height:100px;*/
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  background:red;
  text-align: center;
}


.container > .box {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.title {
  color: #103D65;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.icone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #F4B7DB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
      
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
      
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
      
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
      
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.container{

```
  width:90%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
display:flex;
justify-content:flex-start;
align-items:center;
flex-wrap : wrap;
```

}

.box{

```
margin-top: 33px;
width: 21%;/*
height:100px;*/
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
background:red;
text-align: center;
 flex-basis:30%;
```

}

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex-basis` property on the `.box` selector. As you want 3 items per row, you may keep the basis value somewhere around 30%-33%; considering the padding & margin of the parent container.

```
.box {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* disposition du cadre */

.box {
  margin-top: 33px;
  width: 21%;
  /*
  height:100px;*/
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .07);
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  /* occupy 30% of the total space */
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.container>.box {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.title {
  color: #103D65;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.description {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.icone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #F4B7DB;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">

    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">

    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">
    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">

    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="icone">

    </div>
    <div class="title">
      Heal emotions
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Phasellus nec pretium mi. Curabitur facilisis ornare velit non
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```